# Why doesn't the server receive my POST data?

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome-extension, postdata

I'm trying to send a simple POST to a web service, but the server doesn't seem to get the POST data. This is the ajax:

**popup.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.flags.99k.org/removeFlag.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "UID=6",
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(response)
    {
        $('<p />').text('response: ' + response.success).appendTo($('body'));
    });
```

- I am expecting `response.success` to be `1`, which would mean that the post was successful.
- I could also obtain `0`, which would mean `mysql_query(...)` returned false.
- But instead, I get `-1`, which means that `isset($_POST['UID'])` returns false.

**.../removeFlag.php**

```
<?php
    include("DB.php"); // connects and selects database.
    if(isset($_POST['UID'])) {
        $sql_removeFlag = "DELETE FROM Flags WHERE UID = " . $_POST['UID'] . ";";
        $success = mysql_query($sql_removeFlag);
        $jsonStr = ("{ \"success\":\"" . $success . "\"}");
        echo $jsonStr;
    } else {
        echo("{ \"success\": -1 }");
    }
?>
```

I tried different ways of formatting the data ('uid'=6, {uid:6}, {'uid':6}, ...) but none worked.

The ajax is run from a google chrome extension popup, but I have added the target address to the permissions list.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Ajax POST",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Ajax POST from popup on click.",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
      "flags.99k.org/*",
      "http://flags.99k.org/*",
      "http://www.flags.99k.org/*"
  ]
}
```

Comment: what sort of debugging have you tried?

Comment: @dldnh I don't actually know what else to try. I know that the ajax call goes through but the post data is never received. If I use GET rather than POST, it works fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_encode($array)` to encode an array into JSON.

```
$response['success'] = $success;
$jsonStr = json_encode($response);
```

It's also important to make sure your ajax php file isn't caching anything.

```
header("Expires: Thu, 15 Dec 2011 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

**The above may not be the answer but I hope it'll help you prevent some possible bugs.**

Comment: Thanks, this is good stuff. It does not solve my problem though.